# Rails 3 -- After Failed Sign In, Errors Do No Populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Edit: Hmm this is interested. I just noticed, my signup route is /signup. But, once I submit the information and the form returns invalid, I'm in the route /users .

---

I'm building a simple app to learn rails, and I've learned to set up an authentication system.

Today, I added a new plans table, to make different subscriptions for users. The Plan model has_many users, and users belong to plans. After implementing this, I see that if I enter invalid information, error messages do not show up in the view anymore.

I have the following code in the application.html.erb file for it show up -- >

```
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
```

It works fine on other notices, but it isn't showing the error messages.

One thing to also note, is that if I enter an email incorrectly for example, Rails shows me that it was the problem by highlighting it in red(edited CSS previously to do that). But, the error messages themeselves are nowhere to be found :P

Here's my Users controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:show]

    def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
  plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @user = plan.users.build
    end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index

    if current_user
      redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
    else
    redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to login_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

I did some research, and people have been saying it might because of redirects, but I'm not sure If I'm doing that.

When first visiting the signup though, it's in the form of /signup?plan_id=1, to populate a hidden field with the plan_id in the signup form. When it shows the error screen, the plan_id is no longer there, which I assumed is okay since it already POSTed it. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: You are not setting the flash[:error], this is maybe why it does not show up?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added flash[:error], but it still didn't populate the messages. But, if I added flash[:error] = "Hi", for example, it would show the error message

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. I just noticed, my signup route is /signup 

But, once I submit the information and the form returns invalid, I'm in the route /users .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the error messages you're expecting to see are errors on the `User` object, not stored in the flash. Try this in your view:

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
  <div class="alert"><%= error_message %></div>
<% end %>
```

See the docs for [ActiveModel::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) for more info.

Comment: Okay! This is getting somewhere! I was able to get the errors to show up, but only partially; For some reason, the object that the errors are happening to is not mentioned.

For example, if I left an invalid email, it would say -- "is invalid" , not "email is invalid". 

Do you have an idea as to why that happens?

Comment: The `#each` method returns pairs of attribute symbols (e.g., `:name`) and the associated error messages. To get a full message, you'll want instead to do `@user.errors.full_messages.each`. I'll edit the answer above to reflect this. Really do check out the API doc linked above.